# Server.CreateObject Failed with chiliupload component

Tags: asp-classic

I get the following error with a legacy asp application that I have been asked to help out with.

```
Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'

Server.CreateObject Failed

/site_manager/image_upload.asp, line 27

800401f3
```

The line ofcode that throws the error is shown below:

```
Set fbase = Server.CreateObject("chili.upload.1")
```

As you ahve probably guessed oldschool asp isn't my strong point but from the research I have done it seems as if a component hasn't been registered on the server (I only have FTP access).

What component needs to be regsistered?

Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the registration of the DLL that creates the chili.upload.1 object. Are you trying to run this on a Linux machine?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nathan, I don't have access to the server but I would assume it is a Windows box as it is ASP and would require IIS, unless I missing something? SO am I right in thinking that the server needs the cillisoft (http://sourceforge.net/projects/chiliaspcomp/) componenet registered?

Comment: I downloaded those files and it looks like that isn't what you want. You want a file called "chilidownload.dll" and you want to install it running regsvr32.exe. Apparently they come as part of this package. http://www.levonline.com/files/caspdoc/Ch13_SpicePack70.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to register the Sun Chili!Soft ASP components. Here's the manual on this from 2003:
http://ns7.webmasters.com/caspdoc/html/running_the_setup_program_sun_chili_soft_asp_for_windows.htm. **Note that this only works if you still have the original setup. Otherwise you're out of luck.** Sun Chili!Soft ASP is no longer available and very, very dead.

If you're just interested in file upload functionality on ASP, I can recommend [Free ASP Upload](http://www.freeaspupload.net/). It requires no registration of any components and generally works. I can also recommend [this article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19297/Pure-ASP-File-Upload.htm) on the topic of ASP uploads. If you're willing to shell out some money there are hundreds of components that do the same thing too.

Answer (score 0):

Register the DLL on your computer, and then do this:

- Locate and then click the following registry subkey:
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\
  FeatureControl\FEATURE_IGNORE_ZONES_INITIALIZATION_FAILURE_KB945701
- Note If the FEATURE_IGNORE_ZONES_INITIALIZATION_FAILURE_KB945701 subkey does not exist, you must manually create it. If you're using a 64 bit OS, you may need to use HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\ FeatureControl\FEATURE_IGNORE_ZONES_INITIALIZATION_FAILURE_KB945701 instead
- Right-click FEATURE_IGNORE_ZONES_INITIALIZATION_FAILURE_KB945701,
  point to New, and then click DWORD Value
- Type w3wp.exe to name the new registry entry, and then press ENTER.
- Right-click w3wp.exe, and then click Modify.
- In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.

After setting this registry key, a simple app pool restart will apply the change. No longer will your .NET COM components randomly stop working with no real solution except shuffling application pools!